# Sharepoint 2013 : Increase width and number of characters in search refiner web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, display-template, sharepoint-search, refinement-panel

Is there any way to increase the width and number of characters in search refiner web part in SharePoint 2013? I remember there was this option in SharePoint 2010.

I know we can tweak CSS and increase the width but i cant figure out how to increase the number of characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default if you have a long refiner name you get the following output:

[image: Result type refiner with long display names]

The refiners are set to a width of 160px. So if you want to show the whole refiner, you have to change the width via CSS of these refiners. When changing the width, this will have an impact on the whole search page. A better approach would be to override the ".ms-ref-ellipsis" class. By default it is set to this:

```
.ms-ref-ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

By overriding the class with the following CSS code:

```
.ms-ref-ellipsis {
    /* Let the text wrap to the next line */
    white-space: inherit;
    /* Break long names without spaces */
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You get the following output:

[image: Show the whole display name]